# text could not shown in text_filed in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two columns in "Communication" table i.e "CommunicationMode" and "CommunicationDetail" and column"CommunicationMode" contain value "Phone" and "CommunicationDetail" contain value "1234567891"
and I want to check if CommunicationMode is equal to "Phone" then it put "1234567891" in text_field and the example code is below:

```
<table>
        <% @user_communication.each do |user_com| %>
        <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Phone:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Phone" %>
                <%= text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone", :value => user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
                <% else %>
                <%= text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
                <% end %>
             </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

But `user_com.CommunicationDetail` could not put `1234567891` text_field. Why?

And when I am trying below that:

```
<table>
        <% @user_communication.each do |user_com| %>
        <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Phone:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Phone" %>
                <h3><%= user_com.CommunicationDetail %></h3>
                <% else %>
                <%= text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
                <% end %>
             </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

At this line `<%= user_com.CommunicationDetail %>` it show me `1234567891` i.e phone number.
So, Kindly help me where I make mistake. I am waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `text_field_tag` instead of `text_field`.

```
<%= text_field_tag :phone, user_com.CommunicationDetail, placeholder: 'Phone' %>
```

Comment: I am trying to use text_field_tag instead of text_field, then in the text_field_tag it show me "{:placeholder=>"Phone", :value=>"1234567891"}". Why

Comment: I have updated my answer with the text_field_tag syntax